# Rolling Groupby function based on a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is ordered by id, timestamp:

```
1   2016-05-13 22:21:02.625+00  Deposit 
1   2016-05-13 22:29:26.402+00  Deposit 
1   2016-05-16 00:51:22.835+00  Withdrawal  
1   2019-03-21 21:01:28.528+00  Withdrawal  
1   2019-03-21 21:02:10.509+00  Withdrawal  
1   2019-12-06 23:34:15.194+00  Deposit 
2   2019-12-03 23:21:33.465+00  Withdrawal  
2   2019-12-05 00:51:01.136+00  Deposit 
2   2019-12-06 20:07:11.122+00  Deposit
```

The desire output is below which is just grouped by Deposit/Withdrawal but stops everytime it changes from deposit to withdrawal or vice versa:

```
1   2016-05-13 22:29:26.402+00  Deposit 2
1   2019-03-21 21:02:10.509+00  Withdrawal 3
1   2019-12-06 23:34:15.194+00  Deposit 1
2   2019-12-03 23:21:33.465+00  Withdrawal 1
2   2019-12-06 20:07:11.122+00  Deposit 2
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: So do you want to group by the ID and Deposit/Withdrawal? Just to print the count of deposit and count of withdrawal for each ID?

Comment: Not exactly, if I groupby ID and Type, then it wouldn't account for if an id has a deposit before and after a withdrawal. I want it counted in order so the same id can have multiple counts for deposits or withdrawals

Comment: I think this can be achieved using a while loop and a counter but I was wondering if there is a way to do it more efficiently using groupby

Comment: Is your output correct? Shouldn't  `2   2019-12-06 20:07:11.122+00  Withdrawal 1` be _after_ `2   2019-12-03 23:21:33.465+00  Deposit 2` (if time is correct)?

Comment: ah sorry yes you are correct editing original message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to group your data according ID and Type.

For example:

```
data = [
['1', '2016-05-13 22:21:02.625+00', 'Deposit'],
['1', '2016-05-13 22:29:26.402+00', 'Deposit'],
['1', '2016-05-16 00:51:22.835+00', 'Withdrawal'],
['1', '2019-03-21 21:01:28.528+00', 'Withdrawal'],
['1', '2019-03-21 21:02:10.509+00', 'Withdrawal'],
['1', '2019-12-06 23:34:15.194+00', 'Deposit'],
['2', '2019-12-03 23:21:33.465+00', 'Withdrawal'],
['2', '2019-12-05 00:51:01.136+00', 'Deposit'],
['2', '2019-12-06 20:07:11.122+00', 'Deposit']
]

from itertools import groupby

data = sorted(data, key=lambda k: (int(k[0]), k[1]))    # <-- if your data is sorted by (ID, Time), you may skip this

for v, g in groupby(data, lambda k: (k[0], k[2])):
    g = list(g)
    print(v[0], g[-1][1], g[-1][2], len(g))
```

Prints:

```
1 2016-05-13 22:29:26.402+00 Deposit 2
1 2019-03-21 21:02:10.509+00 Withdrawal 3
1 2019-12-06 23:34:15.194+00 Deposit 1
2 2019-12-03 23:21:33.465+00 Withdrawal 1
2 2019-12-06 20:07:11.122+00 Deposit 2
```

Note: You can sort the time as string. It's in format that allows this.